# Solving Laplace's Equation with point source and a region of fixed value

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Suppose we want to solve Poissons equation$$\nabla^{2}\phi=f$$ for a point source at the origin so
$$f=k\delta(\textbf{r}')$$
then the solution is given by
$$\phi(\textbf{r})=-\int\frac{k\delta(\textbf{r}')}{4\pi|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}d^{3}r'=-\frac{k}{4\pi|\textbf{r}|}$$
I now want to add a volume, $\alpha$, defined by the boundary $\partial\alpha$ that does  not overlap with the origin. In this volume I would like $\phi(\textbf{r})$ takes some fixed value $\phi_{0}$, that is
$$\phi(\textbf{r})=\begin{cases}\phi_{0}\;\text{if}\;\textbf{r}\;\text{is in}\;\alpha\\
\Phi(\textbf{r})\;\text{if}\;\textbf{r}\;\text{is outside}\;\alpha
\end{cases}$$
how do I find $\Phi(\textbf{r})$? I honestly have no clue where to begin so any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
The context of this problem is that I am trying to resolve the electric potential field of a system consisting of a point charge and a conductor held at a fixed potential.

I doubt it's possible to obtain an analytic solution, what I'm looking for is some guidance of how I could set this problem up to be solved numerically. All I know is that
$$\nabla^{2}\phi=k\delta(\textbf{r})$$
and that
we have the boundary conditions that $\phi=\phi_{0}$ on $\partial\alpha$ and $\phi=0$ as any element of $\textbf{r}$ approaches $\pm\infty$.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form solution except for very specific $\alpha$ such as a ball. It would be helpful if you clarify what kind of answer you are looking for (series expansion, integral formula, etc) and what the context for the problem is (e.g. is it from a textbook?)

Comment: I've added a bit more information, hopefully it's a bit clearer now

Comment: I have added an answer which reduces the problem to solving a boundary value problem for Laplace's equation. I don't think there is much more one can do without knowing more about $\alpha$.

Comment: You should look into the Finite Element Method (FEM) if you want to solve this equation numerically for an arbitrarily shaped domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as stated is missing a boundary condition on $\phi$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$. From the context (electrostatics), I assume that the missing condition is $\phi(x) \to 0 \quad \text{as } \|x\| \to \infty$.

I would pose the problem as follows: Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \alpha$ be the domain. Note that $\partial \Omega = \partial \alpha$. We would like to solve the boundary value problem
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = f \quad \text{on } \Omega,\\
\phi(x) = \phi_0 \quad \text{for } x \in \partial \Omega,\\
\phi(x) \to 0 \quad \text{as } \|x\| \to \infty,\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
where $f = k \delta$.
Since the equation is linear, we can use the following approach:
Compute that solution $\phi_1$ to the boundary value problem
$$
\nabla^2 \phi_1 = 0 \quad \text{on } \Omega\\
\phi_1(x) = \phi_0 - k \Phi(x) \quad \text{for } x \in \partial \Omega\\
\phi_1(x) \to 0 \quad \text{as } \|x\| \to \infty,\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
where $\Phi(x) = -\frac{1}{4 \pi x}$ is the fundamental solution. Then we notice that the function $\phi = \phi_1 + k \Phi$ satisfies
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = \nabla^2 \phi_1 + \nabla^2 k \Phi = 0 + f = f.
$$
Moreover, it satisfies both boundary conditions by construction.

Now the problem has been reduced to solving a boundary value problem for Laplace's equation on the (unbounded) domain $\Omega$. The solution certainly exists as long as $\partial \Omega$ is sufficiently regular (Lipschitz), but for most $\alpha$, you may have to resort to numerics.

Comment: hey this was really useful thanks, i can easily obtain the boundary conditions for $\phi_{1}$. Do you have any suggestions of how I could solve this numerically?

Comment: It depends on your purposes. If you have access to Mathematica and you want to quickly get solutions for some relatively simple geometries, that may be your best bet. If you need more flexibility and want to devote some time to this, then the finite element method (FEM) might be best. (1/3)

Comment: If you are new to FEM, I recommend [FEniCS](https://fenicsproject.org/). Chapter 2 of the [FEniCS tutorial book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-52462-7) gives a nontechnical introduction to the FEM and teaches you how to solve the Poisson equation. Unfortunately, the book was written for an older version of FEniCS, so some of the code examples will not work as-is. I refer you to the [FEniCS demos](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/latest/python/demos.html) for working code examples. (2/3)

Comment: FEniCS has simple mesh generation capabilities. If you already have a mesh, you may be able to import it as [shown here](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/latest/python/demos/eigenvalue/demo_eigenvalue.py.html). Otherwise, you might need to use [FEniCSx](https://github.com/FEniCS/dolfinx#installation) which is a new, in-development version of FEniCS. It supports gmsh for mesh generation as [shown here](https://docs.fenicsproject.org/dolfinx/v0.6.0/python/demos/demo_gmsh.html, which should be quite flexible. Unfortunately, the documentation is not as complete as for FEniCS. (3/3)